# Running PyDev refactor from java code?

Tags: java, python, eclipse, plugins, pydev

Is possible to call the `pydev` refactor (passing a new/old class name) from a Java code, such as clicking in a button in an Eclipse plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean in an Eclipse plugin with a dependency on PyDev, then yes, it should be possible...

Take a look at the test-cases for this: com.python.pydev.refactoring.refactorer.refactorings.renamelocal.RenameClassRefactoringTest

Comment: Yes, I meant that.
Is there a easy way to import the method and pass the new/old strings and path? After looking at the code, I did not understand how to make it

Comment: Have you tried running that test-case under a debugger and step in the code to understand how it goes?